# Cleave.js PhoneFormatter not working

Tags: javascript, mootools, cleave

I'm trying to implement **[Cleave.js](https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js)** with **[MooTools.js](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core)** but although I'm doing it correctly (or so I believe, the implementation is very simple) I can't seem to get it to work no matter what.

I also tried testing in a [website given by a contributor](https://rawgit.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html) from the repository's issue tab.

The code is simple as well, I don't know if anyone knows what's the issue and there doesn't seem to be complains other than [this other guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769944/cleave-js-phone-ca) issue which is similar to mine.

**Code:**

```
var CleavePhone = new Class({
    initialize: function()
    {
        window.addEvent('loadCleavePhonesFormatter', this.loadCleavePhonesFormatter);
        window.addEvent('loadCleavePhoneFormatter', this.loadCleavePhoneFormatter);

        return this.loadCleavePhonesFormatter();
    },
    loadCleavePhonesFormatter: function()
    {
        var elements = [];

        $$('input[cleave-type="phone"]').each(function(element){
            elements.push(new Cleave(element, {
                phone: true,
                phoneRegionCode: (element.get('cleave-country-code') || 'MX')
            }));
        });

        return elements;
    },
    loadCleavePhoneFormatter: function(element, country_code)
    {
        return new Cleave(element, {
            phone: true,
            phoneRegionCode: (country_code || 'MX')
        });
    }
});
```

Initialize — in some other part of global scripts (it is being imported and has no problem whatsoever):

```
new CleavePhone();
```